# C++/Arduino Array em classe

Tags: c++, array, classes, ponteiro, arduino

Estou com um problema na utilização de um array de ponteiros, preciso criar um array com ponteiros que referenciem para um valor inteiro de cada objeto de outro classe.

Exemplo:

```
arrayDePonteiros[0] = objeto.int;
```

No caso esse array está dentro de uma classe e como ele será apenas uma referencia ele será estático,Assim poderei utilizar esse array para me referir ao valor de cada objeto da outra classe, que futuramente será gravado em uma eeprom, e no momento que eu for ler o valor na eeprom eu poderei utilizar o ponteiro para passar o valor da eeprom para a variável do objeto.

Meu código atual é:

```
class Scenario {

public:
int byteInicial; // byte da eeprom
static int* link[6]; // atual array de ponteiros



Scenario(int byteI) // construtor da classe
{ 

byteInicial = byteI;
link[0] = &led1.fade;
}
```

Neste caso eu recebo o erro: undefined reference to `Scenario::link'.
Já tentei utilizar

```
Scenario::Scenario link [0] = &led1.fade;
```

Porém recebo o erro ao tentar usar ele de qualquer forma, seja printando na serial ou tentando gravar na eeprom. 
Qual seria a forma correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema ocorre porque variáveis qualificadas como `static` em classes/estruturas devem ser definidas fora da classe alem de ser declarada dentro dela. Sendo assim, em algum lugar do seu arquivo cpp que esta associado a esta classe você deve declarar o array.

```
// Arquivo .h
class Scenario {
public:
    int byteInicial; // byte da eeprom
    static int* link[6]; // atual array de ponteiros

    Scenario(int byteI) // construtor da classe
    { 
        byteInicial = byteI;
        link[0] = &led1.fade;
    }
    // ...
};

// Arquivo .cpp
int * Scenario::link[6];
```

Quanto ao seu código, você realmente quer guardar apenas ponteiro para 1 objeto de cada vez como você esta fazendo ? Nesse caso não seria melhor utilizar um ponteiro normal em vez de um array de ponteiros ? Essas são perguntas que acho que você deve se perguntar.